# Downloading a file sent in response to a POST request via nodejs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, express

I'm having trouble issuing a POST command that downloads a file.

On the client side, I'm trying to POST to a specific URL, including a param that specifies the file to download.

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : '/click',
    data: { 'path' : filename }
   });
req.done(function(data) {
// Download the file here?
```

The server eventually fires off a method which does this:

```
function downloadFile(req, res) {
  var dir = req.session.currentdir + req.body.path;
  mimetype = (shell.exec("file --mime-type '" + dir + "'", {silent:true}).output);
  mimetype = mimetype.substring(mimetype.indexOf(": ") + 2, mimetype.length);

  var stat = fs.statSync(dir);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : mimetype,
                      'Content-Length': stat.size });
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(dir);
  fileStream.pipe(res);
};
```

Now I can't seem to get the client side to accept the file I'm trying to pipe back . . it just hangs for an incredibly long time before closing. What is the appropriate way to get the client to download the file I'm trying to send back?

Much thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I am getting the data in `%PDF-1.4
%���� {more data} %%EOF`, but how should i download the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.
resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"xxxx.xxx\"" );

2.
better to use Get

Comment: Assuming I swithed the ajax to be a GET, I'm still not sure how the client would receive the data.

Comment: If you use Get instead, you can let the browser to download it. Or you can deal with the data in the ajax callback function.

Comment: for example, they get the data in a hidden iframe, and get the data from the iframe.[link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/610641-file-download-ajax)